# Compound assignment operators with self in C++

Tags: c++, compound-assignment

To compute the square of `2.0`, does this code

```
double a = 2.0;
a *= a;
```

have well defined behavior? And, equivalently, with all the other compound assignment operations and build-in types.

Comment: why do you think it does not?

Comment: I don't know. Something bugs me. Wouldn't the standard allow to implement a double, e.g., as two floats, and then the statement could become multiple machine instructions in which the first overwrites the memory location. And then the subsequent instructions produce garbage.

Comment: What's wrong with `a = a * a`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am just curious. Actually, I thought about using that expression, to be sure.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Too verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's legal, because (C++11, §1.9/15): "The value computations of
the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value
computation of the result of the operator" or (C++03, §5/4):
"Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object
shall have its stored value modified at most once by the
evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall
be accessed only to determine the value to be stored."  (In
`a *= a`, the `a` on the left side is accessed only to determine
the value to be stored.  And the evaluation of the `a` on the
left side is a "value computation", without side effects.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

The only reason to believe the contrary would be an issue with [sequence points](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), but that does not apply here.

> 1) Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.

You only modify once, you are good.

Comment: The code is legal, but not for the reasons you quote.  In particular, you ignore the sentence immediately following the one you quote, which says that you cannot (always) access the variable otherwise.  The classical example would be something like `f( a, ++ a )`, where `a` is only modified once, but the expression still has undefined behavior.